# Filter based on a nested value JavaScript / React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects containing data from Google Places API.

The objects have nested arrays/objects and I want to filter my data based on a value from the nested array.

```
data = [
        {
            place : "First",
            address: [
                {
                    "types": [
                        "locality",
                        "political"
                    ],
                    "long_name": "Galway",
                    "short_name": "Galway"
                },
                {
**** I want to filter data from here **********
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ],
                    "long_name": "County Galway",
                    "short_name": "G"
**** I want to filter data from here **********
                },
            ]
        },

        {
          place : "Second",  
          address: [
                {
                    "types": [
                        "locality",
                        "political"
                    ],
                    "long_name": "Dublin",
                    "short_name": "Dublin"
                },
                {
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ],
                    "long_name": "County Dublin",
                    "short_name": "D"
                },
```

I want to filter this data given the value of a select tag.
However I want to use the value where the types array contains "administrative_area_level_1"

ie. "County Galway"

Eg.
If select value = "Galway"
return The first object. etc etc.

This is returning my desired output but I don't know how to incorporate this with a filter function.

```
data.map((item) => {
        item.address.map((item2) => {
            if (item2.types.includes("administrative_area_level_1")) {
                console.log(item2.long_name.split(" ")[1])
            }
        })
    })

// Logs County Galway but after split, Galway
// If this value = <select>...filter
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to filter some of array object, starts with filter function

```
let filtered = data.filter( place => return true/false);
```

Let's write the filter method for a 'place'. What you want first is finding the administrative_area_level_1 in address.

```
let administratives = place.address.find( c => c.types.include('administrative_area_level_1') );
```

Let's assume it can be any size, even empty... You now want to check that at least one has the 'galway' value. So if become

```
boolean isGalway = administratives.some( a => a.long_name === 'Galway' );
```

Put everything together

```
const results = data.filter( place => {
    let administratives = place.address.find( c => c.types.include('administrative_area_level_1') );
    boolean isGalway = administratives.some( a => a.long_name === 'Galway' );
    return isGalway;
});
```

Short if you want

```
const results = data.filter( place => place.address.find( c => c.types.include('administrative_area_level_1') ).some( a = a.long_name === 'Galway' ) );
```

Comment: It's not exactly what you expect but it's a good start, I let you change the `=== 'Galway'` with what you want